# Linq: Orderby when including multiple tables

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Currently learning Linq to Entity. I been successful, but came stumped with the orderby clause and its use with multiple tables.

```
    var query = from k in contxt.pages.Include("keywords") 
where k.ID == vals.pageId select k;
```

My understanding with the code above is it creates an inner join where ID is equal to pageId.

So what I am having a difficult time visualizing is how I would perform an orderby on both tables?
I would like to sort on both tables.

I have tried:

```
var query = from k in contxt.pages.Include("keywords") where k.ID == vals.pageId orderby k.keywords.**?** select k;
```

The question mark is not supposed to be there. I am showing that the column that I would like to sort by isn't there. Trying this k.Kegwords. doesn't show the column.

I would write a SQL query as follows:

```
string query = "SELECT pages.page, pages.title, pages.descp, keywords.keyword
FROM pages INNER JOIN keywords ON pages.ID = keywords.pageID
ORDER BY keywords.sort, pages.page";
```

pages and keywords have a 1 to many relationship, which FK keywords.

Thank you,
deDogs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.

```
          var result = (from x in pages
                      join y in keywords on x.ID equals y.pageID 
                      orderby y.sort, x.page
                      select new
                      {
                          x.Page,
                          x.title,
                          x.descp,
                          y.keyword
                      });
```

Comment: Thank you, nice, so its almost like backward thinking from SQL.